# MBR2GPT.exe conversion in a non-UEFI motherboard INSYDE BIOS 3.6

Tags: windows, startup, bootloader

After I updated my INSYDE BIOS to the latest version 3.6 in my Toshiba satellite laptop, I noticed my BIOS mode is set to Legacy.

In the process of changing to UEFI mode, I realised my motherboard doesn't support UEFI in the first place(so stupid of me)

The conversion was successful but now I need to boot into my Windows 10 OS without losing any data. Though I have backed up important files in my ext hard disk... I need an alternative approach.

Is it possible to reverse the process (gpt to mbr) without losing data?

I have tried the diskpart commands but it asks for an empty drive only :(